# Animate item in drawable layer-list

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, drawable, layer-list

Given a drawable like so:

```
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid  android:color="#FF0000"/>
        </shape>
     </item>
     <item>
         <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/button_down_red"  />
     </item>
  </layer-list>
```

I would like to create an animator to animate the solid color, but I can't seem to find a way to access a property within the layer-list.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do this:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(<id of the layer-list drawable>);
LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
GradientDrawable border = (GradientDrawable) layer.getDrawable(0);
```